# Android:see all devices who are connected to my wifi

Tags: java, android

I am looking to make an app to show the devices in my wifi and not getting to do only with the site documentation android Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'd advise you to [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for how to make better questions and let me welcome you to Stack.

To answer your question, [Android Network Discovery](https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery) gives source code 
which allows you to scan and query all devices and sources connected to your wifi.